# Why doesn't Flow see members of objects in this polymorphic union type?

Tags: flowtype

### The Setup

Here's a complete [try flow example](https://flow.org/try/#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-cELRM8L2+FAFWtXjpXNRUum6dVtV1fVDWNC05TFPjZLlEVqIEiVQBJcgaHaIgTECLAfBwiURVQExQHgchPTOYdNO0nxjKYNB0giNITwJWt2EQeg2EECIAEYQOzKkimgwF+CZFl9iMNirBqC4KKqKLJ00BommCjoen6IZ7mLY4Wi8-8WguOJBy480-FgOzHGM0zzOILSdJoeBbPsoy8SqLE0Vc9zWE8kwE18sCAqMILWmZVkAgi440NAGLsji+LEuaNZNm2XYlgy18spysL4tAYI8CeabWi8hNcvyzifmK0BIBEExoAqsgzLECyaus+q7IiTtMV7dqPMoEx-16itqUC6hguGzbQDGmbMv4AAiQ7-2h07uJjHBRGuxBYz-LB-2TIG9CG0LJHC3sajW4LIC8YZL1zJGfFR6B0d-ACcYG4H8ZGona0hybkNihjm1hVoeeycnYDByc5uSoS0rFmjTup813KcHBGGgOcmGgWm0Yxpncfm0HRuJvmpuaCaocFpyRZlhLQiS1oUr6QYrZja6TGC9wAC9PfdtA8snArZZiamgA) illustrating the issue.

#### Types

```
export type ActionT<TT: string, PT> = {|
  +type: TT,
  +payload: PT,
  +error?: boolean,
  +meta?: any
|}

export type ChangePayloadT = {
  +_change: {|
    +state: 'PENDING' | 'FULFILLED' | 'REJECTED',
    +id: string,
    +error?: any,
    +message?: string,
  |}
}

export type IdPayloadT = {
  id: string,
}

type PayloadT = IdPayloadT | ChangePayloadT

type MyActionT = ActionT<'SET' | 'MERGE', PayloadT>
```

As you can see, `MyActionT` can contain a payload with either an `id` or a `_change` object. It's not quite (?) a [disjoint union](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions) because there isn't a single property to disambiguate on.

This seems like it should work, but doesn't:

```
function lookup3 (action: MyActionT): any {
  if (action.payload._change) {
    // why does this error?
    return action.payload._change.id  
  } else {
    return action.payload.id
  }
}
```

Anyone care to set me straight as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution apparently involved making the the two types a proper disjoint union:

```
export type ChangePayloadT = {
  +_change: {|
    +state: $Keys<typeof asyncStates>,
    +id: string,
    +error?: any,
    +message?: string,
  |},
  id?: string,
}

export type IdPayloadT = {
  +_change?: void, 
  +id: string,
}
```

With the second type now having an explicitly `void _change`, flow knows to tell the types apart based on the presence or absence of a `_change`.

[Working tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiSgMawHYGcAuBDTXbRDHXUfNXASywGkBTAT21AF5QBvRUUAZQCiAFQBcoAORDhEgDS9QAWUEAlAOKDxE5esFyFAEUEAZEZslHTwvfIC+yFGFzMADoxKMAHi9gAnCs5uoACC1HSYwgA8obRYwq6M4ni+NJgA5rKgAAr4zHD4ACbxbgB8HNwAPgoA1IGJIWFxCfJ81S65+QXiOXmwhcWMLaDVjL6+fgD84gBGsLDQjIRD1QC2jARTlJjMiBX2iF4+-qB1oACSBT2dwuU8rQD6aAAWhGmMmwBusDQFmTU-SVwKXSdmQhz8AQSoAAwi90owrn0ircao84W9xFwqnxWgDQMlUhkFK1RuNfJtCMwhq01thsPg3psCSCFHshj8mUDCaDEKdEf1yhd+ciKjD0QiOkjhLyoYpmDFwjdOAq4pEACRMViROqwSCURqYTXYEqZYXCErIVC4J40Ni20CwADWuUQkAArpgDaA3rgAGKpS6+RgFGhofC4RigAAUVFimHEcpVEQAlOJfR6vXdQEHcG7fJhowVkxwylm+DQ9TGDQA6dq9QrVtGvRjFss4nN5gux8K1yUNpvw6s-DjsTgFRvPZtDgrE0C2UCMaDYSNtvgd-P6uO9+vj4ejsfbzrT2f2Pj2faoZeMFZsRgARzdNA++AWRFA0zdFAKsHcmAkFGfaAfnDRhXQzONvXWf1MEDYNQxAgAmaNuywBN5QNYRU1AdNPQgrMK2Qms6yPAc3lbWd1wLKMixLTce2IpEJ3FacRwPBj+0nQcfgUedF2XbgKPWTtC2LdgyhQzBD0YvdR1Acd2N3ApQB4xB9iAA) Yay. :)